# I want to load the page in mobile as in desktop, but it has too much zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, scaling

So i got a client that wants the site to look on mobile exactly like on desktop (small text and all). the issue im encountering is that the site zooms on mobile so i figured im doing something wrong.

i used this code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

with this it loads it zoomed, if i change the initial scale to 0.1 i get white bars around the content and the text gets enlarged.

any idea how to achieve it properly? JS or something?

thank you.

Comment: you need to work on the css using media query... there u can define the look of the site on mobile view

Comment: If you want a site to look the same on different viewports have you considerd sizing everything in terms of viewport width? (You cant get the same vertically in terms of whether the user has to scroll to see stuff or not because of the differing aspect ratios).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media query to make your site mobile-responsive and you only need to add this code in your <*meta*> tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

You can use media query like this. In here 500px is based on mobile device width, It means all css properties in media query will run if your device width is below 500px. Otherwise it will load default css properties which you wrote earlier in the document.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  /*Your
  Changing
  CSS
  Properties*/
}
```

You can learn more about media query in [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).